# Overlayed underlines

Tags: ulem

I want the overlayed underline like the one shown [image: here], but, since the `ulem` package only offer `{}`as enclosing characters, the code `\uline{ab\uwave{cd}ef}` doesn't work. Does anyone have a simple solution to this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED to try to automate.  There are four commands `\tuwave`, `\buwave`, `\tuline`, and `\buline`.  The `t` signifies "top" and the `b` signifies "bottom", depending on whether the squiggle or line are on top or bottom level.  The `wave` commands take one argument signifying the characters to be underset with a wave.  The `line` commands take two arguments, the first are the letters to output, and the second is a text string used to determine the length of the underline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\let\tuwave\uwave
\newcommand\buwave[1]{\raisebox{-3pt}{\uwave{\raisebox{3pt}{#1}}}}
\newcommand\tuline[2]{\stackunder[.6ex]{#1}{\rule{\widthof{#2}}{.2ex}}}
\newcommand\buline[2]{\stackunder[1.2ex]{#1}{\rule{\widthof{#2}}{.2ex}}}
\parskip 1em
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\def\stacktype{L}
\begin{document}
\buline{ab\tuwave{cd}ef}{abcd}\par
\tuline{ab}{abcd}\buwave{cdef}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following example defines `\uwavelow` to get a lowered wave line to avoid clashes with the underline. Also it seems, that `\uwavelow` (or `\uwave`) can be put into `\uline`. But the other way round is more trickier. The example uses a box to hide the `\uline` inside `\uwavelow` (or `\uwave`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand*{\uwavelow}{%
  \bgroup
  \markoverwith{%
    \lower7pt\hbox{\sixly\char58}%
  }%
  \ULon
}

\begin{document}

\uline{ab\uwavelow{cd}}\uwavelow{ef}

{\uline{ab}\sbox0{\uline{cd}ef}\uwavelow{\usebox{0}}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: where to find the defination of `\sixly`?

Comment: @lyl It is defined by package `ulem`: `\font\sixly=lasy6`