# Upside-down syntax trees for linguistics with horizontal lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, linguistics, trees, forest

I know that syntax analysis can be done in Latex using using TikZ, but the tree-structure that produces isn't really used in my country. Here, we mostly use straight lines instead of hierarchy trees.

Here's an example what I want to achieve. I don't know where to start from.

Is there any (more or less) easy way to do it? Any idea?

[image]

---

### Edit:

Even though all solutions provided until the moment are right, it would be nice to modify the following characteristics of the different diagrams you've proposed:

- **The sentence** that is being analysed ("La novela que me ha regalado mi hermana...") **should be on top of the graphic** and all words must be in the same line; "la" can't be immediately over "Det" and "está" shouldn't be immediately over "N/V".
- All the syntax functions of **the differents words** ("OP", "S/SN", "PN/SV", "Det"...) **should be centered with the respective lines they have above** (or at least near to the center but **without having to change manually the spacing**).
- It should be possible to modify **the height of the diagram**.

Comment: Could you please supply some code? I realise you don't know how to draw the diagram but at least provide the document framework and the text which needs to go into the diagram. This makes it a lot easier to try out a solution than trying to start from scratch.

Comment: See http://www.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/.

Comment: Out of curiosity, were you able to figure out solutions to the three items under your “Edit” section?

Comment: Not really, but your answer fits almost what I want to do. However, it would be nice to solve them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here’s a solution that uses the excellent [`forest`](http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest.pdf) package.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

% Node shape adapted from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/data-flow-diagram/
\makeatletter \pgfdeclareshape{myunderline}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \foreach \from in
    {center,base,north,north east,east,south east,south,south west,west,north west}{
      \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\from}
  }
  \backgroundpath{
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    % This can be improved by removing magic numbers
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya+1.75em}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya+1.75em}}
 }
} \makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    fit=band, % Isolates space above this node from siblings’ descendants
    no edge,
    % Uncomment the line below for the dotted edges
    % edge={dotted, semithick, gray!50, shorten <=8pt}, parent anchor=north,
    % This can be improved by reducing space between levels where edges are drawn
    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
    l sep=0pt, s sep=6pt, text depth=0.5em, grow'=north,
    where level=0{} % No style for dummy root node
      {where n children=0
        {font=\bfseries,tier=word} % Leaves in bold on the same tier
        {font=\small,tikz={\node[draw, thick, myunderline, fit to=tree] {};}} % Non-leaves
      }
}
% This can be improved by removing the need for a parent and sibling of the actual root
[,phantom[,phantom][OP
  [S/SN
    [Det [La] ]
    [N/Sust [novela] ]
    [CN/SAdj/Prop Sub Adj
      [PV/SV,
        [\textit{nexo} [que] ]
        [CI/SN [me] ]
        [N/V [ha regalado] ]
      ]
      [S/SN
        [Det [mi] ]
        [N [hermana] ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  [PN/SV
    [N/V [est\'a] ]
    [Attrib/SAdj
      [N [ambientada] ]
    ]
    [CCL/SPrep
      [E [en] ]
      [T/SN
        [N [Australia\rlap.] ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

And here’s another version with faint dotted edges:

> [image]

You can render the same structure in a more conventional appearance just by changing options:

```
for tree={
    edge={dotted, semithick, gray!80, shorten <=1pt,shorten >=3pt},
    parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,
    inner sep=0pt, outer ysep=2pt,
    text depth=0.5em,
    where n children=0{font=\bfseries,tier=word}{font=\small}
}
```

> [image]

So you can see why one might prefer using `forest` instead of `bussproofs` or `semantics`. Also, the `forest` tree syntax is much simpler, and is not “backwards” as seen in [cfr’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172420/46230).

Take a look at the `forest` manual for more style options.

2019 edit:
`fit to tree` option syntax has been modified to `fit to=tree`

2020 edit:
changing `l` as `l=1.5em` changes the vertical spacing

Comment: Nice solution. BTW, how can I reduce the vertical height of the diagram? I've tried `l sep` with negative values without success. Thank you

Comment: Very slick solution. I wish I understood `forest`. I don't see why my solution is 'backwards' though. You are analysing the sentence so that's where you are starting, surely? In that sense, your solution seems to be 'backwards' if anything. Still very nice, though - especially being able to easily turn it upside down like that.

Comment: @JnxF I also tried playing with `l sep`, `inner ysep`, `outer ysep`, and the like with no success, but I thought my solution answered your question enough to still post it. You could post a new question, or just wait for other people who know more about `forest` to stop by.

Comment: @cfr I guess it depends on your perspective :). In my experience, trees are usually specified parent-first — that’s how the syntax (heh) of most of the various tree packages I’ve tried (`forest`, `tikz-qtree`, `qtree`, `synttree`, “plain” TikZ) work. It would be trivial to replace `forest` with any of those if you wanted to, but harder to switch to `bussproofs` or `semantics` since they are specified child-first.

Comment: @htft I don't considerate necessary to ask another question. I've just edited this one.

Comment: @JnxF I suppose — though the last two bullets are not unique to this question.

Comment: When I draw trees, it is usually parent-first but I'm not starting with a sentence as I'm no linguist. If you are analysing language, you start with the language. So *in this context* it is 'backwards' to start at the other end.

Comment: Hi folks, I'm trying to use this snippet, but ... pgfkeys cannot find `/tikz/fit to tree`. Indeed there is not such as option in its docu. so I cannot use your first `tree={}` snippet, ideas?

Comment: I've modified properly the answer. Feel free to undo my changes if you consider it.

Answer (score 7):

For example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[inference]{semantic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\setpremisesend{0pt}
\setpremisesspace{1pt}
\setnamespace{0pt}
\inference{%
  \inference{%
    \inference{\mbox{La}}{Det}
    &
    \inference{\mbox{novela}}{N/Sust}
    &
    \inference{%
      \inference{%
        \inference{\mbox{que}}{nexo}
        &
        \inference{\mbox{me}}{CI/SN}
        &
        \inference{\mbox{ha regalado}}{N/V}
      }
      {PV/SV}
      &
      \inference{%
        \inference{\mbox{mi}}{Det}
        &
        \inference{\mbox{hermana}}{N}
      }
      {S/SN}
    }
    {CN/SAdj/Prop. Sub. Adj}
  }
  {S/SN}
  &
  \inference{%
    \inference{\mbox{está}}{N/V}
    &
    \inference{%
      \inference{\mbox{ambientada}}{N}
    }
    {Attrib/SAdj}
    &
    \inference{%
      \inference{\mbox{en}}{E}
      &
      \inference{%
        \inference{\mbox{Australia}}{N}
      }
      {T/SN}
    }
    {CCL/SPrep}
  }
  {PN/SV}
}
{OP}

\end{document}
```

[image: Tree]

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what exactly the OP wants, or how `semantic` works, but it seems to me a key part is that the lines are the same length as the word(s) they refer to, and yours don't seem to have that. Is that adjustable?

Comment: I mean the words in the sentence above the picture, for example "nexo" refers to "que", "CI/SN" to "me", "N/V" to "ha regalado" and "PV/SV" to "que me ha regalado". You haven't included the sentence in your answer, even though the lines more or less line up with the words they refer to. I'm just under the impression that the lines being the same length as the words is key, since this is a linguistics question and the words below seem to describe parts of the sentence above.

Comment: @JānisL Yes. Sorry. I deleted my comment because I realised what you meant. I am not sure you can (straightforwardly) do that with `semantic` but you can put the words right above the relevant analysis (see edit) so that it is obvious what goes with what. This is the way `semantic` is used on the LaTeX for Linguists site and this option looked like the closest match to the image the OP posted. Another possibility would be to adapt a package intended for typesetting similar kinds of proofs in formal logic. (`bussproofs` is maybe the best known.) But this seemed a little more promising here...

Comment: [prftree](http://ctan.org/pkg/prftree) might be a better option, now.

Comment: Is there any way to get one of those packages (`semantic`, `bussproofs`, `prftree`) to align the uppermost row at the top together?

Comment: @hftf What's wrong with using `forest`? I thought that had the advantage of not being 'backwards' as well? All of these are proof packages, so they are all going to be 'backwards' from your point of view ;). (They are forwards really of course :-).)

Comment: I didn't say anything was wrong with using forest; I am just curious if a solution using one of those proof packages can align the top row.

Comment: @hftf See my other answer. In a nutshell: no. There is no way to get these packages to do that without fiddling significantly with their internals. (Of course, if you change the package *enough*... but I think you are then writing a new package with some bits of code from another one!)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a different way... based on my answer at [Highlighting text through stacked colored underlines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169189/highlighting-text-through-stacked-colored-underlines/169203#169203)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newlength\tmpln
\newlength\lunderset
\newlength\rulethick
\lunderset=1\baselineskip\relax
\rulethick=.8pt\relax
\def\stackalignment{l}
\newcommand\nunderline[3][1]{\setbox0=\hbox{#2}\tmpln=\wd0%
  \stackunder[#1\lunderset-\rulethick]{\strut#2}{%
     \smash{\raisebox{-.6\baselineskip}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\scriptsize #3}}}%
     \rule{\tmpln}{\rulethick}}}%
\let\Nun\nunderline
\let\HS\hspace
\begin{document}
          \Nun{\Nun{\Nun[3]{La}{Det}}{}}{}%
               \Nun{\Nun[4]{ }{}}{}%
          \Nun{\Nun{\Nun[3]{novela}{N/Sust}}{}}{}%
               \Nun{\Nun[4]{ }{}}{}%
\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun   {que}{\itshape nexo}}{}}{}}{}}{}%
     \Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun[2]{ }{}}{}}{}}{}%
\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun   {me}{CI/SN}}{}}{}}{}}{}%
     \Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun[2]{ }{PV/SV}}{CN/SAdj/Prop. Sub. Adj}}{S/SN}}{}%
\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun   {ha}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}%
\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun   { }{}}{}}{}}{}}{}%
\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun   {regalado}{N/V}}{}}{}}{}}{}%
          \Nun{\Nun{\Nun[3]{ }{}}{}}{}%
\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun   {mi}{Det}}{}}{}}{}}{}%
     \Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun[2]{ }{}}{}}{}}{}%
\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun   {hermana}{\HS{5ex}N}}{S/SN}}{}}{}}{OP}%
                    \Nun[5]{ }{}%
          \Nun{\Nun{\Nun[3]{est\'a}{N/V}}{}}{}%
               \Nun{\Nun[4]{ }{}}{}%
     \Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun[2]{ambientada}{\HS{7ex}N}}{Attrib/SAdj}}{\HS{7ex}PN/SV}}{}%
               \Nun{\Nun[4]{ }{}}{}%
     \Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun[2]{en}{E}}{\HS{4ex}CCL/SPrep}}{}}{}%
          \Nun{\Nun{\Nun[3]{ }{}}{}}{}%
\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun{\Nun   {Australia}{\HS{6ex}N}}{\HS{3ex}T/SN}}{}}{}}{}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, and in partial response to a [query in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172415/upside-down-syntax-trees-for-linguistics-with-horizontal-lines/172420?noredirect=1#comment565755_172420) on my [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172420/), here is the tree set with `prftree`. As can be seen, this no more lends itself to typesetting this kind of tree than `semantic`. If anybody wants to typeset natural deduction proofs of this kind for logic, though, it looks like a really nice package with a lot of convenience commands, flexible customisation and a nice syntax. The tree here is very verbose because none of the convenience commands are appropriate: this is definitely a package intended for symbolic logic. The result is very, very slightly closer to the target tree in some ways than with `semantic` but the improvement is marginal, at best, and the result is even further from the target in other aspects.

**My conclusion is that none of `bussproofs`, `semantic` and `prftree` are well-suited to typesetting this kind of tree.** The `forest` and `stackengine` solutions are definitely superior relative to the question desiderata.

**However, *for logic*, these package are superior to the other solutions offered here.** They are designed for that purpose and will produce trees more easily and with less hassle. `prftree` looks especially good, even though this is the first time I've used it. The alignments and spacings are designed to work correctly out-of-the-box for logic, and `prftree` allows you to specify the tree using standard rules of inference, which makes it more readable, less verbose and more intuitive. My conclusion above is not, therefore, intended as a criticism of these packages. They just aren't designed for this sort of tree.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{prftree,geometry,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\prftree{%
  \prftree{%
    \prftree{\text{La}}{Det}
    }{%
    \prftree{\text{novela}}{N/Sust}
    }{%
    \prftree{%
    \prftree{%
        \prftree{\text{que}}{nexo}
        }{%
        \prftree{\text{me}}{CI/SN}
        }{%
        \prftree{\text{ha regalado}}{N/V}
        }
      {PV/SV}
      }{%
      \prftree{%
        \prftree{\text{mi}}{Det}
        }{%
        \prftree{\text{hermana}}{N}
        }{S/SN}
      }
    {CN/SAdj/Prop. Sub. Adj}
    }
  {S/SN}
  }{
  \prftree{%
    \prftree{\text{está}}{N/V}
    }{%
      \prftree{%
        \prftree{\text{ambientada}}{N}
      }
      {Attrib/SAdj}
    }{%
    \prftree{%
      \prftree{\text{en}}{E}
      }{%
      \prftree{%
        \prftree{\text{Australia}}{N}
      }
      {T/SN}
    }
    {CCL/SPrep}
  }
  {PN/SV}
}
{OP}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: <code>prftree</code> proof]

Comment: Another thing is that they all seem to default to math mode :o)

Comment: @hftf Again, given their purpose, that makes sense ;).

Comment: @cfr cannot you force the main sentence vertical alignment?